# Importing a class if and only if runtime reaches inside a block of code

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, sprite-kit, preprocessor-directive

I have a method in which I have a switch statement with almost 60 cases. (It's a level select construct in a game, and each level is a different SKScene object) I haven't tried yet but if i import 60 scenes into another scene, i fear i'll have performance issues. Is there are way to import a class if and only if runtime reaches inside some block of code ?

Comment: "switch statement with almost 60 cases" Really? Brutal!

Comment: "switch statement with almost 60 cases" Instead of doing this you'd better to have only one `SKScene` and 60 plist files with levels data.

Comment: yup, read up in data driven design, there was also a recent sk question regarding the same thing. Essentially you need one class with a currentlevel int to run level-specific code, of which there should be relatively few lines

Answer (score 2):

No. Classes are imported, and more specifically, linked statically.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I found out that this is not possible. Preprocessor directives are executed before compilation (as we know) so there's no way to execute them during/after compile time.